# Datalist and image load using jquery lazyload plugin issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have one datalist and with in item template i have one image tag. i bind the datalist from server side code.

### here is my small code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.lazyload.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("table[id*=dgImages] img").lazyload({
          placeholder: "images/ajax-loader.gif",
          effect: "fadeIn" 
      });
  });
</script> 

<asp:DataList ID="dgImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
      <ItemTemplate>
       <img src='<%# Eval("photos")%>' width="100px" height="100px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is when i am running this sample then all the images downloading at a time which i dont want.
i want only images in browser visible area should download and when scroll down then other visible images should 
download.

i just could not figure out why lazyload is not working in my sample.
so please help me to point out the actual problem and how to fix it

### is this code is ok

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("table[id*=dgImages] img").lazyload({
          placeholder: "images/ajax-loader.gif",
          effect: "fadeIn" 
      });
  });
```

please help me with rectified code. thanks

Comment: Can you add your output html from browser ?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try

```
  $("#dgImages img").lazyload({
          placeholder: "images/ajax-loader.gif",
          effect: "fadeIn" 
      });
```

Comment: ur tips does not work.my dgImages render table at runtime. here i am giving my render html. <table id="dgImages" cellspacing="4"><tr><td><img src='snapdeals/5052603_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" /></td><td><img src='snapdeals/50584602_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" ></td><td><img src='snapdeals/55403401_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" /></td> <td><img src='snapdeals/55572106_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" /></td></tr></table> i just need to know lazy load can not work when image is wrapped with in table. please have a look and give me solution.thanks

Comment: i tried with $("#dgImages img").lazyload({}) but does not work.